# Add Object to array of multiple documents

Tags: mongodb

I'm having some trouble with adding an object to my Mongo collection. Here is my update function:

```
'readMessages': function (chatId) {

    Messages.update({
        "chat_id": chatId,
        "read.user_id": {$nin: [this.userId]}
    }, {$addToSet: {'read.$.user_id': this.userId}});


}
```

I want to find all messages of a chat, that the user didn't read yet. When I call the function, he should update all messages and insert the user_id into the "read" array.

If I do a Messages.find() with my values, he finds 150 messages - that's correct. But when I try to update all message object with the command below, nothing happens - my "read" array is still empty.

What's the correct syntax/way for Mongo to push a new Object to all matching documents?

Answer (score 0):

Think I found the solution by myself:

```
   'readMessages': function (chatId) {

    Messages.update({
        "chat_id": chatId,
        "read.user_id": {$nin: [this.userId]}
    }, {$addToSet: {'read': {user_id: this.userId}}}, {validate: false, multi: true});


}
```